# PYTHON REGEX to search all .sql filenames from a string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm writing a code that checks into Git Repo and finds out what files have been changed after the last (Most recent) commit. Those are the .sql files. I get the output as Follows

```
b'commit 7cc9c8ac247f2c139c37081aef091b78c6d51011\nAuthor: blahblah <blahblah@gmail.com>\nDate:   Wed Oct 17 18:46:37 2018 +0800\n\n    test subprocess output\n\n:000000 100644 0000000... e69de29... A\t123.sql\n:000000 100644 0000000... 617f0a5... A\tabc.sql\n:000000 100644 0000000... e69de29... A\ttestFile1\n:000000 100644 0000000... e69de29... A\txyz.sql\n'
```

Now, I'm stuck at regex to extract the filenames from a string. I can extract these filenames using multiple split, however, that, would be bad and would unnecessarily complicate my code. So, I want to use `re.findall` as it'll give an array of filenames that I've to deal with.

Here, Expected Output is

```
['123.sql','abc.sql','xyz.sql']
```

need help with regex pattern.

Sample Code Example:

```
import re
files = b'commit 7cc9c8ac247f2c139c37081aef091b78c6d51011\nAuthor: blahblah <blahblah@gmail.com>\nDate:   Wed Oct 17 18:46:37 2018 +0800\n\n    test subprocess output\n\n:000000 100644 0000000... e69de29... A\t123.sql\n:000000 100644 0000000... 617f0a5... A\tabc.sqlt\n:000000 100644 0000000... e69de29... A\ttestFile1\n:000000 100644 0000000... e69de29... A\txyz.sql\n'
```

> regex = "HELP REQUEIRED"

```
files = re.findall(regex, files.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Try `re.findall(rb'\w+\.sql', files)`.

Comment: I did not post because your expected results are out of sync with your input. Your string contains no `abc.sql`, there is `"\a"`, an escape sequence for a BELL char.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention, just edited the string

Comment: Ok, so, does my solution work? Shall I post or do the answers below work well enough for you? I am not sure if `files` is a byte string. Is it? Your second code snippet still looks corrupt to me as `b'` is inside the string literal, and on top, it is not.

Comment: yes, your answer worked and files is a byte string as its an output from subprocess.check_output. I converted it to string before doing manipulations

Comment: @Whosoever Downvoted my question - Can you please explain me the reason of your downvote, so it would help me put a better and improved question next time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match one or more word chars followed with a `.` and `sql` substrings, but since `files` is a byte string, you should also prefix the string literal with `b`:

```
re.findall(rb'\w+\.sql', files) 
            ^ ^^^^^^^^
```

**Details**

- `\w+` - 1 or more letters, digits, `_` chars
- `\.` - a  dot
- `sql` - a `sql` substring.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/obCPEN):

```
import re
files = b'commit 7cc9c8ac247f2c139c37081aef091b78c6d51011\nAuthor: blahblah <blahblah@gmail.com>\nDate:   Wed Oct 17 18:46:37 2018 +0800\n\n    test subprocess output\n\n:000000 100644 0000000... e69de29... A\t123.sql\n:000000 100644 0000000... 617f0a5... A\tabc.sqlt\n:000000 100644 0000000... e69de29... A\ttestFile1\n:000000 100644 0000000... e69de29... A\txyz.sql\n'
print(re.findall(rb'\w+\.sql', files))
```

Output:

```
[b'123.sql', b'abc.sql', b'xyz.sql']
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just look for all "words" at the end of lines that end with `.sql` and are separated by a tab character?

```
re = re.compile(r'\t(\w+\.sql)$')
```

If your "SQL filenames" contain whitespace or other weird stuff, you will have to parse the complete line, but it seems that a simpler approach like mine above should be easy to understand and get you there most of the way.

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you?

```
import re
files = "b'commit 7cc9c8ac247f2c139c37081aef091b78c6d51011\nAuthor: blahblah <blahblah@gmail.com>\nDate:   Wed Oct 17 18:46:37 2018 +0800\n\n    test subprocess output\n\n:000000 100644 0000000... e69de29... A\t123.sql\n:000000 100644 0000000... 617f0a5... A\abc.sqlt\n:000000 100644 0000000... e69de29... A\ttestFile1\n:000000 100644 0000000... e69de29... A\txyz.sql\n'"

regex=r"(\w+.sql)"

result = re.findall(regex, str(files), re.M)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['123.sql', 'bc.sql', 'xyz.sql']
```